# Are there any meaningful differences between old and new Belisarius series?

Tags: eric-flint

It seems that the original [Belisarius series](http://www.baen.com/series_list.asp?letter=B#BEL) by Eric Flint and David Drake was recently republished as a trilogy, combining 2 books in 1.

E.g. "Belisarius I Thunder at Dawn" = "An Oblique Approach" + "In the Heart of Darkness"

Are there any meaningful differences between old and new Belisarius series that would make the new editions worth reading for someone who read the old series? Or is it straight up republish with may be some minor SPAG fixes?

Answer (score 1):

I have read both offerings there is no difference whatsoever. Two complete novels in one volume—the beginning of the Belisarius saga. [http://www.amazon.com/Belisarius-I-Thunder-Dawn/dp/1416555684/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416555684)